# Why would some popular NuGet packages be missing from my package manager?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

This has only just started happening to me, and I'm not sure why.

I simply can't seem to find some nuget packages that I know are on the official feed.

For example: `AutoMapper`.

- This is the package that I'm trying to add: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/3.0.0
- Running `Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 3.0.0` in the package manager console tells me that no such package could be found
- Searching for `AutoMapper` in the Manage NuGet Packages window only returns a prerelease version (`3.3.0-ci1017`)

The URL I have for the feed is `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/`.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what may be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have likely changed NuGet to `Include Prerelease` packages. Just change the dropdown back to `Stable Only`.

Comment: That was it, thanks. I didn't even bother to check this as I presumed that even if this was set to `Include Prerelease` that it would include pre release as well as stable releases.